# Native Extension for Air for iOS - email, sms, twitter, facebook

Tags: air, air-native-extension

I am a Adobe Flash Builder and Flash CS5.5 user for making mobile (Android, iOS) apps. Currently, I am looking for native extensions for Air allowing me to share content via e-mail, sms, twitter and facebook for iOS.

At this time, I use the url-schemes mailto and sms, but this has some major drawbacks.

On Android I've managed to use the native extensions made by SSD.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

here is one for sharing via email:

http://flashsimulations.com/2011/11/30/ios-native-extension-for-adobe-air-in-app-mail-composer/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give a go at this http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/
Its paid a paid one though but sounds good to me - never used it.